# My sql connection timeout while fetching large data

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have more than 1 lac users in tbl_user table and I want to select all user id's and by using each 
user id I am trying to get lifetime points & used points by and then available points for each user
as stated below,

```
   $get_all_userid_qry = "SELECT user_id FROM tbl_user WHERE site_id=12345 AND             active='1'";
   $get_all_userid = $con->fetchAll($get_all_userid_qry);

    //echo '<pre>';print_r($get_all_userid);exit();

   $available_points_array = array();
   $points_threshold_Distribution_data = array();

   $userCount = count($get_all_userid);



    for($i = 0; $i < $userCount; $i++)
    {
        $name_points_qry =  "SELECT sum(earned_points) as points FROM tbl_points WHERE site_id=12345 AND user_id='".$get_all_userid[$i]->user_id."' ";
        $name_points_row = $con->fetchRow($name_points_qry);

        $lifetime_points = $name_points_row->points;

        //get used points by user

        $get_used_points = "select sum(points_used) as used_pts from tbl_claimed WHERE site_id=12345 AND user_id='".$get_all_userid[$i]->user_id."' ";
        $get_used_points_row= $con->fetchRow($get_used_points);

        $used_points = $get_used_points_row->used_pts;

        $available_points = $lifetime_points - $used_points;
        $available_points_array[] = $available_points;
    }
```

but, I am finding difficulty in selecting all user id's from tbl_user as my sql connection gets time out in between and it is not displaying full array of result when I am using print_r().

Please suggest what to do for selecting that much large amount of data .

Comment: Do you have an index on `(site_id, user_id)`. Also, are you really doing a separate query for each user ID? Why not a single query with `GROUP BY user_id`?

Answer (score 0):

Just before your opening php tag enter:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
```

Or you can add this line in your htaccess file:

```
php_value memory_limit 64M
```

Hope it helps!